# Why does Chrome DevTools debugger screen appear green when debugging chromecast?

Tags: google-cast

When I use the Chrome DevTools debugger to debug a chromecast custom receiver the screen is green.

I have disabled hardware acceleration in Chrome. This happens on both Windows and Mac. It happens from all PCs in my home.

No error messages are provided. Here is what it looks like.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sir i think there might be something wrong with the chromecast,

i had the similiar issue here.
i want to debug webview app using emulator and it just shows green screen but i still tap on the screen. then i using real device to test my app and it works. it shows the page how it should be.